# How to show entire Decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, converters

I have a variable like this:

```
string energyA14 = "0.17"; //kWh
```

which I then add to a property like so:

```
EnergyA14 = Convert.ToDecimal(energyA14)
```

but when I print it out it only shows 17 I want it to show 0.17

How do I make so the entire Decimal is shown?

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This looks like `C#`, but you should tag your language to make it clear.  Is `EnergyA14` a `decimal` or a `double`?  What does your print statement look like?

Comment: *but when I print it out it only shows 17*, print it out how?

Comment: I print it out using a WPF datagrid that is bound to the object containing this property EnergyA14

Comment: can you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's a problem of the used culture.
So the `.` is not interpreted as decimal delimiter, resulting as the number `17.000`.

Try use the other overload of [`Convert.ToDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
EnergyA14 = Convert.ToDecimal(energyA14, CultureInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Same for [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
decimal.TryParse(energyA14, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantInfo, out EnergyA14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `decimal.Parse` or `decimal.TryParse` method:

```
string energyA14 = "0.17"; //kWh
decimal EnergyA14;
if (decimal.TryParse(energyA14, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out EnergyA14))
{
    // EnergyA14 is set here
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `if`, the variable is set in the `out` part

Comment: @christiandev yes, but what if the string cannot be parsed?

Comment: There's no mention of it in the question, so the variable will just be defaulted.

Comment: @christiandev I agree, the `if` is not required. But I also believe it's better to know whether the string was parsed to `0` or it was defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on exactly what you want to see?

When I try

`string energyA14 = "0.17"; //kWh
 decimal EnergyA14 = Convert.ToDecimal(energyA14);`

I see 0.17. Is this what you want to see or something else?

Also, would this be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx